# this.props.navigation.navigate not working in onAuthChanged()

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

I'm new to programming in React Native and decided to dive in the deep end by also integrating Firebase functionalities. I have all my layout working but face an issue when I try to code for Firebase authentication.

The problem is at the very start (splash screen) where I check if the user is authenticated or not (**onAuthChanged**). 
If the user object has been loaded, then I want to redirect to a login page when the user object is null and to the loading (main) page when there is a valid user object.

Wanted to use a simple react-navigation this.props.navigation.navigate call when these criteria are met but nothing happens. There is no redirect and also no errors.

Pretty sure it must be a basic error on my part but I can't find it. 
All the relevant code is in ComponentDidMount()

**SplashScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

import { Transition } from "react-navigation-fluid-transitions";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

class SplashScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.unsubscriber = null;
    this.state = {
      userLoading: true,
      user: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      console.log("User object = " + JSON.stringify(user));
      console.log("1 - this.props");
      console.log(this.props);
      this.setState({ userLoading: false, user });
      if (!this.state.userLoading && this.state.user) {
        console.log("Loading screen");
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Loading");
      }
      if (!this.state.userLoading && !this.state.user) {
        console.log("Login screen");
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.unsubscriber) {
      //this.unsubscriber();
      firebase.unsubscriber();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#587AA0",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
... more layout of the splash screen
}
}
export default SplashScreen;
```

The console.logs all print out the correct values (user object and this.props.navigation.navigate is present)

It's just that nothing happens :( No redirect and no errors

This code is for SplashScreen.js which is a StackNavigator Screen called from App,js

**App.js**

```
    const LoginStack = FluidNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {
      screen: SplashScreen
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen
    },
    Setup: {
      screen: SetupScreen
    },
    Tour: {
      screen: TourScreen
    },
    Loading: {
      screen: LoadingScreen
    },
    Main: {
      screen: MainTab
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoginStack />;
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong or suggest a better method of dealing with this? Thanks

Comment: `setState` is not instantaneous (it is async), are you sure that the code enters into any of the `if` statements?
You should never use `setState` and then check the state for the values as they might not be present yet.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is triggered only once immediately after the initial rendering.

this.setState is not instantaneous. In your case, this.setState is completely executed AFTER this if block.

```
if (!this.state.userLoading && this.state.user) {
    console.log("Loading screen");
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Loading");
}
if (!this.state.userLoading && !this.state.user) {
    console.log("Login screen");
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
}
```

Hence, that `if` block won't be executed because this.state.userLoading is still false.

Never expect setState to be synchronous or instantaneous, it's exactly the opposite.

The solution is just remove userLoading and immediately navigate to the next screen after this.state.user is determined.